# What are pros and cons of magnetic and mechanical door latch?

Tags: doors, furniture, hardware

There such small latches that can be screwed up to cabinets wall and door.
There two types: magnetic ones and mechanical (with a spring).
Like this (magnetic):
[image]

And this:

[image]

Magnetic ones seem to be very strong and seems don't lose strength over time. And prices are approximately the same (in general). So, why would I prefer one before the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnetic ones are simpler imho, and don’t have so much to catch a sleeve on. Also, the tongue on the mechanical one can deform over time.

Comment: By the time I've got answers, my already deformed (after several days), not tongue, but catching part though.

Answer (score 1):

Some magnetic catches have neat functions like push in  release and the door opens enough to allow fingers to open the door, when closing pushing in fully closes the door, I like those more than the mechanical style. As far as life of the hardware I have remodeled 20’s & 30’s houses that had the mechanical clasps that were still functional so I think ease of installation would be easier for the magnet style as the plate can be offset and the magnet style still work.